# в PyPy input() или sys.stdin.read(1) никак не хотят принимать что либо кроме английских букв и цифр(Короче всё кроме стандартного)

Tags: python, pypy

```
self.ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
File "C:\Users\Gode\Desktop\py\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Если буду вводить допустим "hello", то пропустит, если -> "Привет", то ошибка.

Comment: покажите код, который вызввает данную ошибку? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jack_oS а он показан в самой первой строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, видимо, работаете на `Windows`. Входной поток, видимо, перенаправлен из файла. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) говорит что в этом случае кодировка входного потока `ANSI codepage`. То есть однобайтовая. Подозреваю что файл хранит текст в кодировке UTF-8.

Кодировка для строк внутри интерпертатора Python - UTF-8. Кириллические символы в ней представлены двумя байтами. Вы считываете один байт (из-за однобайтовой `ANSI codepage`) и функция `sys.stdin.read` преобразовывает его в строку. Но ни первый, ни второй байты буквы `П`, например, нельзя преобразовать в строку. По-отдельности они не имеют смысла. О чём вам и сообщает интерпретатор.

Чтобы исправить приведите кодировку файла к ожидаемой. Или иcпользуйте [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING), или [-X utf8](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id5), или [PYTHONUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUTF8).

Так или иначе надо добится чтобы кодировка источника байтов совпала с кодировкой `sys.stdin`.

Comment: Я недавно перешел к PyPy. С кодировкой в оригинале все нормально, однако при переходе на PyPy(Примерно когда задал этот вопрос), возникла ошибка с кодировкой. Сейчас я не за ПК, и позже(примерно, через 9-13 часов) буду следовать вашей инструкции.